# Add keys in associative php array as per reference

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have an array, so I wanted to add keys to each value, for example, if an array contains Facebook URL then the key should be Facebook if an array has a link of Instagram then the key should be Instagram and the list goes on.

Here's the code

```
<?php
foreach($social_media as $social){

$typesocial = $social['type'];
if($social['type'] === 'social network') {
$val[] = $social['url']['resource'];
}

}
print_r($val);

?>
```

```
Array ( 
[0] => https://plus.google.com/+beyonce
[1] => https://twitter.com/Beyonce
[2] => https://www.facebook.com/beyonce
[3] => https://www.instagram.com/beyonce/
[4] => http://www.weibo.com/beyonceofficial 
)
```

It should become, if the value has a link of  twitter then the key should be twitter if Instagram then it should be Instagram

```
Array ( 
[google] => https://plus.google.com/+beyonce
[twitter] => https://twitter.com/Beyonce
[facebook] => https://www.facebook.com/beyonce
[instagram] => https://www.instagram.com/beyonce/
[weibo] => http://www.weibo.com/beyonceofficial 
)
```

Comment: Ok what have you tried? Please post your code.

Comment: @Sammitch here's the code
<?php
                            foreach($social_media as $social){

    $typesocial = $social['type'];
    if($social['type'] === 'social network') {
      $val[] = $social['url']['resource'];
    }

}
print_r($val);

                        ?>

Comment: Put it in your question, not a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This maybe? Hope to help

EDITED

```
$array = Array ( 
0 => 'https://plus.google.com/+beyonce',
1 => 'https://twitter.com/Beyonce',
2 => 'https://www.facebook.com/beyonce',
3 => 'https://www.instagram.com/beyonce/',
4 => 'http://www.weibo.com/beyonceofficial',
  6 => 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/a/witty/documentary'
);
$output = Array();
foreach($array as $key => $url){
 $urlarr = parse_url($url);
 $arr = explode('.',$urlarr['host']);
 $name =  $arr[count($arr) - 2];
  if($name == 'co'){
    $name =  $arr[count($arr) - 3]; 
  }
 $output[$name] = $url;
}
print_r($output);
```

Comment: What happens if the URL contains ebay.co.uk like .co.uk domain etc?

Comment: your solution is working pretty well. I will accept your answer

Comment: I guess you would need to make an exception then true! if that is required i could edit! Let me know if it is required and you need a solution

Comment: Please add, would be great if it can support any kind of domain including parameters etc

Comment: I should say: urls are very unpredictable things, so you never know what may not work, but regular structured urls should work :)

Answer (score 1):

```php
$indexed = [
'https://plus.google.com/+beyonce',
'https://twitter.com/Beyonce',
'https://www.facebook.com/beyonce',
'https://www.instagram.com/beyonce/',
'http://www.weibo.com/beyonceofficial',
];
```

Assuming the host consists of 2 or 3 parts

```php
$assoc = [];
foreach($indexed as $url) {
    $host = explode('.', parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST));
    switch (count($host)) {
        case 2:
            $assoc[$host[0]] = $url;
            break;
        case 3:
            $assoc[$host[1]] = $url;
   }
}
```

Will output $assoc as

```
array(5) {
  'google'    =>  string(32) "https://plus.google.com/+beyonce"
  'twitter'   =>  string(27) "https://twitter.com/Beyonce"
  'facebook'  =>  string(32) "https://www.facebook.com/beyonce"
  'instagram' =>  string(34) "https://www.instagram.com/beyonce/"
  'weibo'     =>  string(36) "http://www.weibo.com/beyonceofficial"
}
```

Comment: This would stop working for domains like .co.uk - for example listing to an ebay.co.uk or amazon.co.uk store or a similar type of service...

Comment: @simandsim Yes, that's true. But for the given examples it works well.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to use [strpos()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) so you can find the words and add specific key, something like this:

```
$new_array = [];
foreach($old_array AS $value){
    if(strpos($value, 'facebook')) {
        $new_array['facebook'] = $value;
    }elseif(strpos($value, 'instagram')) {
        $new_array['instagram'] = $value;
    }elseif(strpos($value, 'twitter')) {
        $new_array['twitter'] = $value;
    }else{ //so it goes...
        $new_array['unknow'] = $value;
    }
}
```

Of course if you have two url with facebook, the second will overwrite the first one so depends of what you need you may add an aditional index... like:

```
$new_array['facebook'][] = $value;
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

An quick/easy-ish way to approach this might be to do a regex match on the domains.

For example, if you have a finite set of social media and can trust the middle of the domain name, then you can extract that part of the url to put it as part of your key.

For example the regex `/google|twitter/` would match `google` from `https://plus.google.com/+beyonce`. This can then be used for your key.

So looping through your set, you'd run `preg_match` which would attempt to find the key based on the domain name. `preg_match` has a parameter called `$match` that then stores the `google` part of what you're matching. You can use this to be the key of your formatted array.

```
$array = [
    'https://plus.google.com/+beyonce',
    'https://twitter.com/Beyonce',
    'https://www.facebook.com/beyonce',
    'https://www.instagram.com/beyonce/',
    'http://badmedia.com/beyonce',
    'http://www.weibo.com/beyonceofficial'
];

$keyed = [];

foreach ($array as $i => $url) {
    preg_match('/google|twitter|facebook|instagram|weibo/', $url, $match);
    $key = isset($match[0]) ? $match[0] : 'notfound-' . $i;
    $keyed[$key] = $url;
}
```

The result here is that `$keyed` now contains your array for `$keyed['google']` and the others.

Add or remove from the `google|twitter|facebook|instagram|weibo` to have a `|another` where you want to have more or less support for different sites.

It's not very scalable, and if the domain doesn't match a key you want to use, then in this case I've set it to create a key called `notfound-` with the original array key. (I've added `badmedia.com` to the list to demonstrate it.). You also run the risk of having a conflict where someone might be smart and have their Facebook username as "nottwitter" which will technically match "twitter"

So what you might want to consider rather than relying on the domain to provide your key for you, to keep a regex match for each full domain name. You could store these regex queries against the key you wanted to use, and nest your two loops to find a match...

For example:

```
$socialMedia = [
    'facebook' => '/^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?facebook.com\/[a-zA-Z0-9(\.\?)?]/',
]

foreach ($array as $url) {
    foreach ($socialMedia as $key => $regex) {
        if (preg_match($regex, $url)) {
            $keyed[$key] = $url;
        }
    }
}
```

(Shoutout to https://gist.github.com/atomicpages/4619196 for the full FB domain regex)

For very small sets (which I imagine you're dealing with at any one time) this would scale slightly better and give you a better result... It also rejects and removes any you don't support, but you would need to catch those separately.

For larger sets you probably want to look at how you collect the urls in the first place... Rather than accept *any list*, maybe have the form or API call you're receiving these from state which one it is on the way in.

Comment: What happens if the URL contains `https://twitter.com/Beyonce+live+on+facebook`?

Comment: Yeup, I mention that in my answer.! It steps through from an intro of the idea of how to use regex in a simple way, then outlines the pitfalls (like other social media names in user names) and what you might do to introduce a full url match.. then noting the possible performance issue and proposing how the set of urls get put together in the first place.. Horses for courses, but hopefully helpful info...